# Alternative to subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using Mysql 5.1, and have this query, is there a way to not use the subqueries and accomplish the same result?

```
SELECT oref.affiliate_id, ROUND(sum( oph.amount ) * 0.10 ,2) AS tsum
FROM operators_referer AS oref 
LEFT JOIN operators_payments_history AS oph 
ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id
WHERE oref.affiliate_id = 28221
AND
(
    oph.date_paid > 
    (
        SELECT MAX(aph.date_paid) 
        FROM affiliates_payments_history AS aph 
        WHERE aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id
    )
    OR 
    (
        SELECT MAX(aph.date_paid)
        FROM affiliates_payments_history AS aph 
        WHERE aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id 
    ) 
    is NULL
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and your expected result?

Comment: Instead of `ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id`, you could use `USING (operator_id)`.

Comment: @glglgl and that doesnt change anything..

Comment: Not with respect to the question, right. That's why I chose to comment and not to answer. Bit it improves readability.

Comment: What is the goal? Is the query running too slowly, or do you need compatibility with something that does not support sub-queries, or is this just because you are aesthetically displeased with sub-queries?

Comment: @David Manheim, this is a part of a complex update, performance is a issue but more than that i want to **know**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't Do it!**
If tables are indexed properly, and the database structure makes sense, you are almost definitely better off leaving this with subqueries. Per you comment, it seems as though this will simplify and speed things up - but that ain't necessarily so. The parser will not necessarily do a better job with a non-subquery form. The clarity of the subquery, and the complexity of a query re-written not to use subqueries, argues that this isn't a worthwhile goal.

**You need-to-know-if-it-can-be-done? It can:**
Answers to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129/do-subqueries-add-expressive-power-to-sql-queries) CS.stackexchange question show how to do so, and some point out that there is no way to have a subquery that cannot be written as a join-based query, with no possible set-differences. That means that there is a way to simplify it, and some links to algoithmic ways to do so are linked to.

Comment: It was pointed out to me that, depending on the query optimizer, the particular subqueries here may be run one-row-at-a-time, instead of having the engine refactor it. If it is very slow, you can try one of the queries with `HAVING`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a `HAVING` clause?

```
SELECT oref.affiliate_id, ROUND(sum( oph.amount ) * 0.10 ,2) AS tsum
FROM operators_referer AS oref 
LEFT JOIN operators_payments_history AS oph 
ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id
LEFT JOIN affiliates_payments_history AS aph
ON aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id
WHERE oref.affiliate_id = 28221
GROUP BY oref.affiliate_id
HAVING MAX(aph.date_paid) > oph.date_paid OR MAX(aph.date_paid) IS NULL
```

Comment: Having is just a sneaky way of creating a subquery. It does eliminate the syntax, but I think the database engine still sees it as a subquery - of course, this may be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
  SELECT oref.affiliate_id, ROUND(sum( oph.amount ) * 0.10 ,2) AS tsum
    FROM operators_referer AS oref 
    LEFT JOIN operators_payments_history AS oph 
    ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id
   LEFT JOIN affiliates_payments_history AS aph ON aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id
    WHERE oref.affiliate_id = 28221
  GROUP BY oref.affiliate_id
  HAVING IFNULL(MAX(aph.date_paid),0 > oph.date_paid)
```

Comment: -1 Your using a sub query, he asks for an answer which does not use one

Comment: do you need the ifnull? If it's a left join isn't it returning the entire oref table, and all records that match in the right table regardless of if they are null or not?

Comment: But at least, the subquery is used only once. It is an improvement over the version in the question; IMO no need to -1.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot remove it, since the condition check is not for equality, but for >, Had it been for equality, could have joined that

Comment: @glglgl You have a point, though he did say without sub queries, I'll reverse my -1 though cos I suppose it is a bit harsh

Comment: Edited my query, please check

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(aph.date_paid) AS max_aph, 
       oref.affiliate_id, 
       ROUND(sum( oph.amount ) * 0.10 ,2) AS tsum
FROM operators_referer AS oref 
LEFT JOIN operators_payments_history AS oph 
       ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id
LEFT JOIN affiliates_payments_history AS aph 
       ON aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id
WHERE oref.affiliate_id = 28221
AND (oph.date_paid > max_aph OR max_aph is NULL)
```

Not tried, but I think this is what you're searching.

Comment: This gives me an unknown column 'max_aph', for some reason the alias is not working down there. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a simple `JOIN` logic.

like so:

```
SELECT oref.affiliate_id, ROUND(sum( oph.amount ) * 0.10 ,2) AS tsum
FROM operators_referer AS oref 
     LEFT JOIN operators_payments_history AS oph 
            ON oref.operator_id = oph.operator_id
     LEFT JOIN affiliates_payments_history AS aph
            ON aph.operator_id = oref.affiliate_id
WHERE oref.affiliate_id = 28221
AND ( oph.date_paid > MAX(aph.date_paid)
OR MAX(aph.date_paid) IS NULL)    
GROUP BY oref.affiliate_id;
```

what the query means is basically "join the aph and oph tables to oref, apply the max function only within the scope of the oref.affiliate_id, and look for rows where the conditions apply"

It would be wise to learn more about the `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` functionality in the MySQL manual

Comment: When running your query i get an 'invalid use of group function' error, i tried to arrange it but still no good, any hint?

Comment: @Juanma - have you tried removing the `oref.affiliate_id` from the `WHERE` section?

Comment: How would will i get the info for the specific id then?